# Qual a diferença do PWA e TWA (Trusted Web Activities)?

Tags: android, google-chrome, pwa

Por acaso estava vendo as novidades do Chrome, e vi um *post* 
[Using Trusted Web Activities](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa), nele diz:

> Trusted Web Activities are a new way to integrate your web-app content such as your PWA with your Android app using a protocol based on Custom Tabs.

Nesse artigo cita que o TWA precisa de um PWA, então precisamos cumprir as exigências do PWA para ter um TWA. Mas, ele não menciona qualquer vantagem direta do TWA em relação ao PWA, exceto o possível fato de poder publicá-lo na Play Store.

O TWA é apenas um PWA publicado na Google Play? É possível publicar fora da Play Store? Qual é a diferença do TWA e de um PWA, ou melhor, de um Webviewer e um TWA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O ponto principal de um TWA é realmente estar disponível na Play Store (como um APK) e por isso precisa se conformar com suas regras, por outro lado ganha alguns direitos (mínimos) que antes não conseguia com um PWA e integra melhor com o *browser*. Não vejo porque publicar fora da Play Store, não há vantagens claras que faça ter interesse nisso.

Tem alguns outros pequenos detalhes que faz a aplicação poder rodar de forma ligeiramente diferente, um desses pontos é que ele pode rodar dentro de uma aplicação ou como uma aplicação isolada, mas ambos usam um WebView.

TWA, pelo menos até agora, é algo só suportado pelo Chrome.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).